# OS X alternative to eventfd

Tags: linux, macos, event-handling

[eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) is Linux-specific. I need to port a library written on Linux which makes use of this event notification system to OS X. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options are a `pipe` and `kqueue`'s `EVFILT_USER`. It depends on how exactly `eventfd` is being used.

Comment: Indeed, a `pipe` fixed my problem.